# Calibrating Gamecube C-stick

Tags: controllers, emulation, nintendo-gamecube

I have gone through the default windows calibration menu like a gazillion times and everything works fine, except my c stick. It is always recognized as slightly to the left and any small movement is recognized as pushing the stick further than possible

Comment: If it's a real GameCube controller it should be self-calibrating. Make sure its centred when you plug it in. You can also recalibrate it by rotating the C-stick at full extension in a circle. Your problem may be with your adapter or driver.

Comment: Are you using your controller in Dolphin?

Answer (score 2):

On a real GameCube, you could cause the various analog inputs to recalibrate by holding down X, Y and Start for 3 seconds. If the problem you're having is only within Dolphin, this should clear it up.